# How to impersonate logged in user to manage other Azure service

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-sdk-.net

I have webapp to make changes in ADF (kinda deployment of objects in ADF). I want to authenticate user against ADF. I am able to detect who is accessing web app. I get Azure AD Id like user1@company.com. I want to validate if the same user has access to ADF and if yes, generate bearer token to make changes in ADF (using rest api) or using SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the way below to get the access token when the user login to the web app, no need to validate if the same user has access to ADF, because if he does not have the access, the token will not be able to call the rest api, he will get the 401 unauthorized error.

1.First, make sure you have [configured your web app to use Azure AD login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad), then navigate to the [resource explorer](https://resources.azure.com/) -> find your web app -> add `["resource=https://management.azure.com"]` to `additionalLoginParams` like below -> `PUT`.

[image]

2.Navigate to the `Azure Active Directory` in the portal -> `App registrations`  -> find the AD App corresponding your web app -> `API permissions` -> add the permission `user_impersonation` of `Azure Service Management` like below.

[image]

[image]

3.Then when the user login the web app, after he consents the permissions,  you can get the token with endpoint `https://webappname.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me`, and use the token to call the [data factory rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/v2).

[image]

4.Make sure the user has an RBAC role e.g. `Contributor` in your subscription/ADF, then the token will be able to call the rest api successfully.

For example, I test with [`Pipelines - List By Factory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipelines/listbyfactory) api, it works fine.

[image]

Comment: After user impersonate permission i'm still facing issue.it's giving me "AADSTS650057: Invalid resource. The client has requested access to a resource which is not listed in the requested permissions in the client's application registration. Client app ID: xxxxxx-5f89-xxxxx-a49d-xxxxxx. Resource value from request: https://management.azure.com. Resource app ID: 797f4846-ba00-4fd7-ba43-dac1f8f63013." Please help. should i add something in scope ?