# Getting access token for scope from azure-appservice using easyauth

Tags: python, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-msal

I am creating a very small webapp in python/Flask, running under the Azure App Service. The app is protected with Azure AD authentication, which relies on easyauth. The app registration has two configured permissions/scopes: `https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read` (to get info about the current user) and `https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation` (to run queries on the Azure management infrastructure).

Whenever I access the app, I have to login. That is good. I am provided with a number of headers, including `X-Ms-Token-Aad-Access-Token` which seems to contain an access token.

When I access Microsoft Graph (thus using the `https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation` scope), all is good (I took away some error handling, for space and clarity):

```
@app.route("/userinfo")
def userinfo():
    token = request.headers.get("X-Ms-Token-Aad-Access-Token")

    data = requests.get(
        "https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo",
        headers={ 'Authorization': f"Bearer {token}" },
    ).json()
```

When I run pretty much identical code to get the list of web apps, it fails with a simple "AuthenticationFailed" code (also without error handling):

```
@app.route("/webapp")
def webapp():
    token = request.headers.get("X-Ms-Token-Aad-Access-Token")
    data = requests.get(
        f"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription_id}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites?api-version=2019-08-01",
        headers={ 'Authorization': f"Bearer {token}" },
    ).json()
```

I suspect that the token provided by the app service / easyauth does not support the `https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation` scope, even though that is specified in the web application setup. But I have no idea, really. It Does Not Work, though. I know that.

The obvious questions: Is this possible? Am I missing something obvious? Is there an easy solution?

(Using MSAL instead of the declarative mechanism seems to work, but I was hoping to use the platform services as much as possible)

Comment: I see that Jason Pan @jason-pan does not believe this has anything to do with azure appservice, and has taken away those tags. That is incorrect, it is tightly related to azure appservice.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization opens with "Azure App Service provides built-in authentication and authorization capabilities (sometimes referred to as "Easy Auth")", and that is the technology this question relates to. I can't find a way to restore the relevant tags, but would appreciate it if someone could fix this.

Comment: I took a look and found that this problem is caused by a mistake in your use of aad, so I said it has nothing to do with azure web app. It is because your concept and usage of Azure Ad are rather vague.

Comment: Firstly, **ONE** access token is only for **ONE** resource. It's impossible that you use the same access token to access Microsoft Graph and Azure Rest API. And this "When I access Microsoft Graph (thus using the `https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation` scope), all is good" is impossible, because you have to specify the scope as `https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read`, then the access token is for Microsoft Graph. I'm not sure what's wrong with your implementation, but I believe what I have clarified is helpful to your understanding of AAD authentication.

Comment: @AllenWu: Yes, my text is of course wrong. When I access Microsoft Graph, I am indeed using the `https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read` scope. And the trouble is of course how to access a token which provides access to `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions` using the `https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation ` scope.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

To call the Azure REST API, you need to leverage the `additionalLoginParams` in the `authsettings` of your web app, navigate to the [resource explorer](https://resources.azure.com/) -> find your web app -> add `["resource=https://management.azure.com"]` to `additionalLoginParams` like below -> `PUT`.

[image]

After the configuration, when the user login the app, it will let you consent the permission `https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation`, after the consent, the `X-Ms-Token-Aad-Access-Token` will be able to call the Azure REST API i.e. `https://management.azure.com`, but it will not be able to call Microsoft Graph any more, because one access token can only for one API resource, to get the user info, you can hit `https://webappname.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me` directly, it will include the user info. Also, make sure your user account has the RBAC roles in your subscription e.g. `Contributor`, `Owner`, because the permission of the token comes from the user.

For more details, see this [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63070576/how-to-impersonate-logged-in-user-to-manage-other-azure-service/63126085#63126085).

Comment: How does this work with auth v2?