# Call microsoft graph from java app service

Tags: java, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-web-app-service

I have a java azure app service with easy auth (auth enabled via azure portal, app registration automatically created).  I'm trying to print out the user's display name on the page but I can't call microsoft graph, keeps giving me an "BadRequest Error message: /me request is only valid with delegated authentication flow".

```
TokenCredential credential = new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build();

List<String> scopes = Arrays.asList("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default");

TokenCredentialAuthProvider tokenCredentialAuthProvider = 
    new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(scopes, credential);

GraphServiceClient graphClient =
  GraphServiceClient
    .builder()
    .authenticationProvider(tokenCredentialAuthProvider)
    .buildClient();

User me = graphClient.me().buildRequest().get();
```

Answer (score 1):

> BadRequest Error message: /me request is only valid with delegated authentication flow

The above error usually occurs if you do not use **delegated** flows as auth providers while calling `/me` request. The code you mentioned is for **client credentials** that does not includes user interaction.

***I tried to reproduce the same via Postman and got below results:***

Using client credentials flow, I generated **access token** with below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type: client_credentials
client_id: <appID>
client_secret: <secret>
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I included above access token while calling `/me` request, I got **same error** as below:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
```

**Response:**

[image]

To resolve the error, you need to use **delegated** flows that involves user interaction like authorization code flow, username password flow etc...

In my case, I used **authorization code** flow where you need to generate `code` initially with below request:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
?client_id=<appID>
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri= https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope= https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
```

When I ran above request in browser, I got `code` in ***address bar*** along with redirect URL after signing in successfully like below:

[image]

Now, I generated access token using **authorization code** flow via Postman with below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:authorization_code
client_id: <appID>
client_secret: <secret>
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
code: <paste code from above request>
redirect_uri: https://jwt.ms
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used above access token while calling `/me` request, I got **user profile** successfully like this:

[image]

To do the same from Java, you can make use of below **sample code** of authorization code flow from MS Documentation:

```java
final AuthorizationCodeCredential authCodeCredential = new AuthorizationCodeCredentialBuilder()
        .clientId(clientId)
        .clientSecret(clientSecret) //required for web apps, do not set for native apps
        .authorizationCode(authorizationCode)
        .redirectUrl(redirectUri)
        .build();

final TokenCredentialAuthProvider tokenCredentialAuthProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(scopes, authCodeCredential);

final GraphServiceClient graphClient =
  GraphServiceClient
    .builder()
    .authenticationProvider(tokenCredentialAuthProvider)
    .buildClient();

final User me = graphClient.me().buildRequest().get();
```

**Reference:**

[Choose a Microsoft Graph authentication provider - Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=Java#authorization-code-provider)

Comment: Oh I did try that, both AuthorizationCodeCredention and OnBehalfOfCredential both just throw "Error executing the request", no information, no nothing.  I included DefaultAzure in my example cause at least it threw a less cryptic exception.  https://i.snipboard.io/310Lna.jpg

Comment: You are passing access token in authorizationCode, could you include how you get that token? Alternatively, try using [username/password](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=Java#usernamepassword-provider) flow once for testing purpose.

Comment: https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo with Bearer [x-ms-token-aad-access-token] works!!!  Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66835707  Now how do I turn that into java using GraphServiceClient?

Comment: I GET THE CODE FROM request.getHeader("x-ms-token-aad-access-token")
I'm already inside an AUTHENTICATED APPLICATION, the user used AD to login before they ever touched my code.  All my code has to go on is that token.  This is an AZURE APP SERVICE WITH EASY AUTH

Comment: Can you decode the token you got from `request.getHeader("x-ms-token-aad-access-token")` by pasting it in https://jwt.ms website and check `aud` and `scp` claims?

Comment: "scp": "email openid profile" "aud": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000"  That's coming from my app registration's permissions https://i.snipboard.io/LhNMiV.jpg

Comment: As you are already authenticated, you can directly call **Microsoft Graph** using this token. Can you try calling `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me` with Bearer [x-ms-token-aad-access-token]?

Comment: Nope, gives me "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
"message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252711/discussion-between-sridevi-and-user433342).

Comment: I missed this step https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scenario-secure-app-access-microsoft-graph-as-user?tabs=azure-resource-explorer#configure-app-service-to-return-a-usable-access-token