# Interacting with Azure Service from Azure Function from Client app on behalf of the user (user impersonation)

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, authorization, azure-storage

**Context**

I have a client app, represented through an Azure Active Directory app that needs to send a HTTP request to a HTTP trigger Azure Function on behalf of the user that is logged in to the client app. To achieve that I followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad. Doing so I am successfully able to execute the function on behalf of the user.

**Goal**

From this triggered Azure Function on behalf of the user I want now to achieve that I can interact with another Azure Service (let's say an Azure Storage Account) on behalf of the user. The user can do on this Storage Account what is allowed by the roles the user has on the Storage Account.

**Problem**

I don't get it working. I tried the approaches described in [How to impersonate logged in user to manage other Azure service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63070576/how-to-impersonate-logged-in-user-to-manage-other-azure-service) and https://blog.brooksjc.com/2020/06/21/accessing-graph-api-with-an-azure-function-through-impersonation/ And in this context I also don't get it working for Azure Data Factory respective Graph as described in the posts. For instance, when I call .auth/me I just get an empty array.

**Question**

Given this context how can I achieve my goal of interacting with the Storage Account on behalf of the user via the Azure Function that has been triggered on behalf of the user?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I am aware of the OAuth 2.0 On-Behalf-Of flow (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow) and this one works (i.e., I am able to authenticate the user, retrieve another token and use this one to interact with the Storage Account on the users behalf). What I would like to achieve is similar to the posts shared above that the user authenticates against the app and by doing so already a token is made available for the interaction with the Storage Account, so that I don't have to make the additional request to [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenant_id}}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7B%7Btenant_id%7D%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token) to get that token using e.g. client credentials. And this is not about specific code (e.g. C#) but about the general set up. Is this possible?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the user must be authorized to invoke the Function (i.e. you pass access token as authorization header when the user invokes Function). Now in your Function code, you want to get another token so that you can execute Azure Resource APIs. Is my understanding correct? Can you edit your question and include the code that you have in your Startup.cs class?

Comment: See EDIT for more information